# Show the Items in the Folder location and not the full directory

Tags: c#, getdirectories

I have an array with of folders in a Directory. 
I want them displayed in the combo-box but I don't the full directory to display, I just want the folder names in the directory. 
I haven't been successful with what I have tried

MY CODE

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetDirectories(@"\\Mgsops\data\B&C_Poker_Builds\Release_Location\Integration\SDL\SP\Prima\");

            ProjectDir.DataSource = filePaths;

            ProjectDir.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

MY RESULT

[image]

Comment: You can use the string method substring : string shortfilename = filename.Substring(filename.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);  I used filenames this morning to do similar which is the code I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the DirectoryInfo class - you can do something like this:

```
string folder = new DirectoryInfo(path).Name;
```

To get an array (using System.Linq), you could do the following:

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetDirectories("<yourpath>").Select(d => new DirectoryInfo(d).Name).ToArray();
```

Or, even use the DirectoryInfo class to enumerate your directories:

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo("<yourpath>");
string[] filePaths = dir.GetDirectories().Select(d => d.Name).ToArray();
```